# Increasing C size of a VM in Azure

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, azure

I followed this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk) for increasing C drive size of a Windows Server 2016 VM.

However when running:

`Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VM $vm`

I get the following error:

`Update-AzureRmVM : 'Vhd' cannot be null.`

Does someone know how can I resolve the issue, or just have another way to increase the C size of the machine?

Comment: Your VM uses managed disk or unmanaged disk?

Comment: It uses managed

Comment: The article works for unmanaged disk.

Comment: Where do you see it there?

Comment: I test according to the article, unmanaged disk works fine. When I use managed disk, `Update-AzureRmVM : Managed disk resize via Virtual Machine 'shui2' is not allowed` I get the error log. You could use Azure Portal to increase your C drive. I test in my lab, it works for me.

Comment: Increase C driver size on Portal works on managed disk and unmanaged disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article works for unmanaged disk. If you use managed OS disk, you could resize your OS disk on Azure Portal.

1.Stop your VM.

2.Resize OS disk on Portal.`<your VM>--<OS disk>`
[image]

3.Start your VM

4.RDP into the VM, open Computer Management (or Disk Management) and expand the drive using the newly allocated space.
[image]

Comment: It likely does not apply in this case but versions before Windows Vista would not allow you to extend the system partition from within Windows.  You would have to use another VM, attached the virtual HDD to it, and extend it that way.